# cant find a word with strpos in smarty (prestashop)

Tags: php, html, prestashop, smarty

I am going to edit the .tpl that generate delivery slips in prestashop.

I want to check if one product in the order contains a particular word in title.
If the title contains that word, then I will generate a table in html

After a simple research, I've find that some users used `strpos` to do that, but my edit doesn't work:

```
    {if strpos($order_detail.product_name, 'word') !== false}
    ...
    {/if}
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't use the `strpos` function in smary's `{if}` statement.

[`{if},{elseif},{else}` documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl) states:

> If securty *(sic!)* is enabled, only PHP functions from $php_functions property of the securty policy are allowed. See the Security section for details.

The [Security sections](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl#advanced.features.security) says:

> $php_functions is an array of PHP functions that are considered trusted and can be used from within template. To disable access to all PHP functions set $php_functions = null. An empty array ( $php_functions = array() ) will allow all PHP functions. The default is array('isset', 'empty', 'count', 'sizeof', 'in_array', 'is_array','time','nl2br').

`strpos` is not in this list.

So it seems that Security is enabled on your part.

You should use `strpos` in your program logic and store the result into a variable which you then check in the smarty template